# Установка Joomla 2.5.6 на Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: joomla, ubuntu

Ubuntu 12.04.

На неё установлены апач, пхп5, mysql, php5-mysql, mysql-server mysql-client.

В общем, localhost полностью работоспособен.
Файловая система - папка var - папка www (в ней хранятся папки с сайтами).
Если я устанавливаю джумлу в папку www, то всё устанавливается, все установки поддерживаются.
Если я создаю в папке www папки с сайтами и пытаюсь установить джумлу в одну из них, скажем, в папку mysite, то не поддерживается JSON.

[image]

Да, установщик пишет, что

> Вы можете продолжить установку, после чего в конце будет показана конфигурация. Вам будет необходимо выполнить ещё один дополнительный шаг - загрузить код вручную. Нажмите на следующем поле, что бы выделить весь отображаемый код, скопируйте его и вставьте как новый файл и назовите его configuration.php, затем загрузите этот файл на ваш сервер в корневую директорию сайта.

Но хотелось бы с самого начала как надо установить.
Как это решить?

Comment: Права на запись: 

    сhmod 777 /your/folder/where/config/configuration.php

Comment: Это для чего команда? Я не работала раньше с убунтой, объясните подробнее, пожалуйста.

Comment: Это устанавливает право на запись на файл , в вашем случае это *configuration.php* . По умолчанию, там настройки бд будет пустыми, и когда вы запускаете мастер установщика, оно будет у вас запрашивать пароль- логин, и т.д параметры вашего БД. И пытается записать эти параметры в настроечный файл, если не сможет записать, обычно из за ограничение доступа, то просить вас самому создать/записать эти данные в configuration.php файл.

Answer (score 1):

Собственно, на скрине видно что `JSON` как раз таки поддерживается и он тут вообще не при чём. Слово "нет" относится к правам записи в файл конфига `joomla`. Вам верно ответили в комментариях, что нужно изменить права на файл. `JSON` трогать не надо.

Comment: кстати да, извиняюсь, не обратил внимания

Answer (score 0):

Или поставьте права 777 на файл `configuration.php`, или установите себе `json` -
выполните в терминале: `sudo apt-get install php-services-json`.